# Server client using select()

Tags: c

I want to implement a server-client monothreaded, using `select();`
For the server part, I took the code from http://www.binarytides.com/code-tcp-socket-server-winsock/ and for the client, the site does not provide some code, they use `netcat` to simulate the client. So, for the client, I am using this code:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <winsock2.h

#pragma comment(lib,"ws2_32.lib")

int main(void) {

struct sockaddr_in si_other;
int s, slen=sizeof(si_other);
char buf[512];
char message[512];
WSADATA wsa;

//Initialise winsock
printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2),&wsa) != 0)
{
    printf("Failed. Error Code : %d",WSAGetLastError());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
printf("Initialised.\n");

//create socket
if ( (s=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("socket() failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

//setup address structure
memset((char *) &si_other, 0, sizeof(si_other));
si_other.sin_family = AF_INET;
si_other.sin_port = htons(8888);
si_other.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");

//start communication
while(1)
{
    printf("Enter message : ");
    gets(message);

    //send the message
    if (sendto(s, message, strlen(message) , 0 , (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, slen) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("sendto() failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    //receive a reply and print it
    //clear the buffer by filling null, it might have previously received data
    memset(buf,'\0', BUFLEN);
    //try to receive some data, this is a blocking call
    if (recvfrom(s, buf, BUFLEN, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &si_other, &slen) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("recvfrom() failed with error code : %d" , WSAGetLastError());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    puts(buf);
}

closesocket(s);
WSACleanup();

return 0;
 }
```

Even the server and the client have the same port, the client always returns -1 meaning that he don't send any message to server. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong here? Any tips would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: *What* return `-1`? Which network function fails? When it fails what error-code does [`WSAGetLastError`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms741580(v=vs.85).aspx) give you?

Comment: Oh and never use `gets`. ***Never*** use `gets`! It is dangerous, have been obsolete since the C99 standard and removed completely from the C11 standard.

Comment: When I connect the client, the server does not entry in if to show the message "New connection , socket fd is %d , ip is : %s , port : %d \n" ..

Comment: Since you're suing UDP you don't "connect" to the server. And the client-code you show seems correct so what makes you think it's not a problem in the "server"? I also recommend you read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) by Eric Lippert, and step through the code line by line in a debugger to see what and where the problem occurs.

Comment: Seems like if your server is waiting tor a TCP/IP connection while the client sends UDP datagrams.

Comment: What's the difference between a tcp connection vs udp connection?

Comment: If you don't know that, then I suggest you take a few steps back and start over from the beginning with networking. Your first task should be to *read books* about it, to learn the basics or networking in general, and of course about TCP/IP. Then you should learn yourself what the difference is. Don't try to run before you can stand.